# Angular2 How to get json form Yahoo Finace rest api

Tags: javascript, angular, yahoo, yahoo-finance

im working on some application, which have to get data from Yahoo finance rest api. For example for symbol "GOOG"i have write this code to get table

```
export  class ActService{ 

act = [];
  url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=&q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol=%22goog%22';
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  constructor(private http : Http){
    this.getAct();
  }

  getAct() {
    console.log("update");

    return Observable
      .interval(1000)
      .flatMap(() => {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
          .map(res => res.json());
      });
  }
}
```

code for app component to use actService:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  act =[];

  ngOnInit(){

    this.actService
      .getAct()
      .subscribe(
        act => this.act = act,
        err => console.error(err)
      );

  }

  constructor( private actService: ActService){}
}
```

This working sometimes fine, but often this is throwing an error.

```
"No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.quotes"
```

The problem is I am reciving this error while I'm starting my application, and in random moments. Specialy often when the date is: any hour any minute, 00 seconds. I have good get when 15:34:59, but in 15:35:00 I have errror.
[image]
How to solve it? It is my fault? I don't see anything bad in my Service, and my "get".

I read last problems in stack about this error, but there wasn't similiar solution to me.

Comment: @ValLeNain from there: err => console.error(err)

Answer (score 0):

I find this problem too and fix it with update my YQL query from YQL console on yahoo developer site.

You can try your query on yahoo yql console here https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/ (dont forget to check "Show community tables" option). For example like this :

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.quotes+where+symbol+in+(%22AAPL%22)

Base on your query, YQL console will give you REST query that you can use on your app. Copy it to replace you current query.

Comment: Yea, I get this rest from here, but it still throwing 404 from time to time - Did You test what frequency of asking rest is the best?

Comment: Nope. Have you try to run it again on YQL console? because I get different result from my old query and new rest query run well.